# Get user input from form, write to text file using php

Tags: php, forms, input, user-input

As part of a subscriber acquisition I am looking to grab user entered data from a html form and write it to a tab delimited text file using php.The data written needs to be separated by tabs and appended below other data.

After clicking subscribe on the form I would like it to remove the form and display a small message like "thanks for subscribing" in the div.

This will be on a wordpress blog and contained within a popup.

Below are the specific details. Any help is much appreciated.

The Variables/inputs are

```
$Fname = $_POST["Fname"];
$email = $_POST["emailPopin"];
$leader = $_POST["radiobuttonTeamLeader"];
$industry = $_POST["industry"];
$country = $_POST["country"];
$zip = $_POST["zip"];
```

$leader is a two option radio button with 'yes' and 'no' as the values.

$country is a drop down with 40 or so countries.

All other values are text inputs.

I have all the basic form code done and ready except action, all I really need to know how to do is:

How to write to a tab delimited text file using php and swap out the form after submitting with a thank you message?

Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 10):

```
// the name of the file you're writing to
$myFile = "data.txt";

// opens the file for appending (file must already exist)
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');

// Makes a CSV list of your post data
$comma_delmited_list = implode(",", $_POST) . "\n";

// Write to the file
fwrite($fh, $comma_delmited_list);

// You're done
fclose($fh);
```

replace the , in the impode with \t for tabs

Answer (score 3):

Open file in append mode

```
$fp = fopen('./myfile.dat', "a+");
```

And put all your data there, tab separated. Use new line at the end.

```
fwrite($fp, $variable1."\t".$variable2."\t".$variable3."\r\n");
```

Close your file

```
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// format the data
$data = $Fname . "\t" . $email . "\t" . $leader ."\t" . $industry . "\t" . $country . "\t" . $zip;

// write the data to the file
file_put_contents('/path/to/your/file.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND);

// send the user to the new page
header("Location: http://path/to/your/thankyou/page.html");
exit();
```

By using the header() function to redirect the browser you avoid problems with the user reloading the page and resubmitting their data.

Answer (score 0):

To swap out the form is relatively easy. Make sure you set the action of the form to the same page. Just wrap the form inside a "if (!isset($_POST['Fname']))" condition. Put whatever content you want to show after the form has been posted inside the "else{}" part. So, if the form is posted, the content in the "else" clause will be shown; if the form isn't posted, the content of the "if (!isset($_POST['Fname']))", which is the form itself will be shown. You don't need another file to make it work. 
To write the POSTed values in a text file, just follow any of the methods other people have mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best example with fwrite() you can use only 3 parameters at most but by appending a "." you can use as much variables as you want.

```
if isset($_POST['submit']){
    $Fname = $_POST["Fname"];
    $email = $_POST["emailPopin"];
    $leader = $_POST["radiobuttonTeamLeader"];
    $industry = $_POST["industry"];
    $country = $_POST["country"];
    $zip = $_POST["zip"];

    $openFile = fopen("myfile.ext",'a');
        $data = "\t"."{$Fname}";
        $data .= "\t"."{$email}";
        $data .= "\t"."{$leader}";
        $data .= "\t"."{$industry}";
        $data .= "\t"."{$country}";
        $data .= "\t"."{$zip}";

    fwrite($openFile,$data);
    fclose($openFile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Very very simple:**
Form data will be collected and stored in $var
data in $var will be written to filename.txt
\n will add a new line.
File Append Disallows to overwrite the file

```
<?php
$var = $_POST['fieldname'];
file_put_contents("filename.txt", $var . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
exit();
?>
```